# How to create a scroll that jumps down in increments the size of your viewport

Tags: html, css, scroll

I am trying to code an extremely basic website with html and css. Every time you scroll I want it to scroll the entire length of the window and a new paragraph (centered) to appear. I drew a picture to get the idea across. This is the code I've come up with so far and I'm hitting blanks. I haven't opened my text editor for almost....2 years and this my first project since. I need help.

Even if you could give me language so I can better find tutorials on how to achieve what I am trying to achieve...that would be awesome. :) Thnx

Right now my centered text is fixed, which I know is a problem.

```css
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;

}

article {
  width: 42.5%;
  margin: auto;

}


p {
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-family: Times New Roman;
}


a {
  text-decoration: none;
}


.content {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


.menu a {
  display:block;
  color: #000000;
}

.menu a:hover{
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #000000;
  
}

.menu {
  float: right;
  clear: left;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>hellomynameischristian</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/hellomynameischristian.css">

  </head>
  
    <body>
      
      
      
      <div class="menu">
        <a href="../html/hellomynameischristian.html">homepage</a>
        <a href="https://www.behance.net/christianmorgan2">design portfolio</a>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/christian.m.morgan/">follow me on ig</a>
      </div>
      
      <div class="content">
         <p>
                     Centered text.


            </p>
          
        
      </div>
           
      
  
   
   
          
    
  
  
  
    </body>
</html>
```

[Sketch of desired webpage layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBvoJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sketch I added:

- A navigation container which menu elements, which will have `position: fixed`, `top: 20px` and `right: 20px`, use the values which fit your needs. Also `display: flex` so the items are displayed as row. Keep in mind that the values are added to the `<ul>` tag, and not `<nav>`.
- Three div containers with text content. Each div has `display: flex`, `justify-content: center` and `align-items: center`, which will center the child elements horizontally and vertically to the center.
- Each div container **will have `width: 100%` and `height: 100vh`**, so remove the height and width value you added to the HTML in your css styling.

Hope this clears a bit more your situation, use flexbox, he's your new friends.

And here is a snippet:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.part1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #2980b9;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}

.menu li {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.part2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #2c3e50;
}

.part3 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #16a085;
}
```

```html
  <nav>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Item1</li>
      <li>Item3</li>
      <li>Item4</li>
      <li>Item5</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <section class="part1">
    <p>I am centered</p>
  </section>

  <section class="part2">
    <p>I am centered</p>
  </section>

  <section class="part3">
    <p>I am centered</p>
  </section>
```

After that, you can add this one-page scroll with a nice animation: http://peachananr.github.io/onepage-scroll/Demo/demo.html

You would only have to wrap your `<section>`'s in a div.

```html
<div class="main">
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
</div>
```

Comment: ohmygoodness thank you so much! i cant wait to try this out